# Gambler's ruin problem, but with modification

Tags: probability

**QUESTION:**[image]

**Solution:**[image]

How did we get to know in the solution that the initial fortune of gambler A and gambler B should be 3 dollars each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is described is simply a random walk.

The probability to get one step up and the probability to get one step down
are each $\frac{1}{2}$ in the fair case.

The starting point (0) means that the player A has 3 dollards. If he wins, the
random walk gets one step up. If +3 is reached, A has won 3 dollars and B is ruined.
If player B wins, the random walk gets one step down. If -3 is reached, player A has
0 dollars, hence he is ruined.

In the fair case, each player has a chance of $\frac{1}{2}$ to be ruined because
the probability that the game goes on foreever, is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is "Suppose."  What they're doing in the solution is showing that the problem can be translated into a gambler's ruin problem.  The reason for supposing that the two gamblers start with 3 dollar each is to make the problem's stopping rule agree with the natural stopping rule of gambler's ruin, namely that the game is over when one person no longer has money to bet.